# Why warning when scala.language.implicitConversions is not the last import?

Tags: scala, import, warnings, implicit-conversion

In my Scala code, I have some implicit conversion, and I have the necessary import present:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
```

However, sometimes when there is another import done after this one, I get the warning as if the import is not there at all:

> Warning:(112, 18) implicit conversion method pair2Dimension should be enabled
>   by making the implicit value scala.language.implicitConversions visible.

**build.sbt:**

```
name := "ImplicitSBT"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation","-feature")

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "1.0.1"
```

**Main.scala:**

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.swing.{Action, _}

object Main extends App {

  implicit def pair2Dimension(pair: (Int, Int)): Dimension = new Dimension(pair._1, pair._2)

  val dim : Dimension = (0,0)

  println(dim)


}
```

Why does this happen? How is `import scala.swing.{Action, _}` hiding the `implicitConversions` import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is import scala.swing.{Action, _} hiding the implicitConversions import?

Your:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
```

... gets shadowed by `implicitConversions` [defined](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/swing/package.scala#L18) in `scala.swing` package object:

```
package scala

...

package object swing {

...

implicit lazy val implicitConversions = scala.language.implicitConversions

...

}
```

---

Since you are using wildcard import here:

```
import scala.swing.{Action, _}
```

... `scala.swing.implicitConversions` gets imported from `scala.swing` and in the end shadows `scala.language.implicitConversions`.

The interesting question is: why `scalac` fails to figure out that language feature is enabled if there are two "feature flags" (`implicitConversions` in this case), one shadowing another at the same level.

This might be a bug as well as specifics of how [SIP 18](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nlkvpoIRkx7at1qJEZafJwthZ3GeIklTFhqmXMvTX9Q/edit#heading=h.p8y95rkd4ydi) is implemented.

Anyway, to solve this I can suggest you to do one of the following:

1. do not import `scala.language.implicitConversions` (as it is already imported when wildcard importing `scala.swing`)
2. do not do wildcard import from `scala.swing` (do not pollute your scope and import what you need instead)
3. do another import (that is not shadowed by another) of `implicitConversions` at your `Main` object level

Comment: To be clear: the interesting question isn't why the two collide (that's expected), but why they don't when the `scala.language` import comes second.

Comment: @Travis I think a specific (one-name) import has precedence over a wildcard import done before it.

Comment: @Suma oh, right, that makes sense. So this isn't too mysterious at all.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html

a wildcard import (as you wrote) gives to any Swing implicit definitions a quite high priority and that's clearly hiding yours.

Since you're compiling with SBT, wouldn't it be much easier to pass the following setting

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-feature",
  "-language:implicitConversions"
)
```

and stop worrying about what's the right place to import `scala.language.implicitConversions`?

Comment: Somehow I find import cleaner than a compiler option. May be just me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the implicit lookup.

Here is the same structure in more normal code, where the required implicit is the execution context.

(It doesn't matter whether the wildcard import is from a package object, or whether the other package is in the same compilation unit.)

Since the code compiles with an explicit `global`, it should compile with an implicit arg.

An implicit is available if it can be [accessed without a prefix](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicit-parameters-and-views.html#implicit-parameters).

The [binding precedence](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html) is not affected by source code order. Shadowing works in the usual way; a binding never shadows a binding of higher precedence.

```
/*
package object bound2 {
  implicit lazy val global = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
}
*/
package bound2 {
  object B {
    implicit lazy val global: concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
  }
}

package bound {
  // the order of these imports in the same scope should not matter
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import bound2.B._

  object Test extends App {
    val f = concurrent.Future(42)  //(global) // explicit arg works
    Console println concurrent.Await.result(f, concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

In the spec example 2.0.1, adding the line marked "OK" compiles, and you can verify that order doesn't matter, but it becomes ambiguous in the inner scope because the "wildcard y" there does not shadow the "explicit y" from the outer scope:

```
    import X.y           // `y' bound by explicit import
    println("L16: "+y)   // `y' refers to `Q.X.y' here
    import P.X._
    println("OK: "+y)   // `y' refers to `Q.X.y' here

    locally { val x = "abc"      // `x' bound by local definition
      import P.X._       // `x' and `y' bound by wildcard import
//        println("L19: "+y) // reference to `y' is ambiguous here
```